# WPF TextBox selectall and show caret at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, caret, selectall

after a long search on the net, I hope you can help me.

My Problem:
I want to select the complete text in a TextBox 
and will show the caret (blinking cursor) after the last character.

Always I have found information about one problem or information to hide the caret.

The separate things are no problems but the combination of it don't work.

```
// Set the focus to the TextBox
myTextBox.Focus();

// Select the complete text, but hide the caret (blinking cursor) 
myTextBox.SelectAll();

// or
// myTextBox.Select(0, myTextBox.Text.Length);

// Set the caret after the last character, but loss the selection from the text
myTextBox.CaretIndex = myTextBox.Text.Length;
```

---

So, I see the caret after the last character, but the text is not selected

```
myTextBox.Focus();
myTextBox.SelectAll();
myTextBox.CaretIndex = myTextBox.Text.Length;
```

And so, the text is selected, but no caret is shown.

```
myTextBox.Focus();
myTextBox.CaretIndex = myTextBox.Text.Length;
myTextBox.SelectAll();
```

---

And that's the problem: one of them deactivate the another one, but I need these two things at the same time

*I using WPF and .Net 4.0*

*Thanks for helping :-)*

Comment: There is a good reason the caret isn't displayed when text is selected: typing will result in the selected text being overwritten (not have new characters appear after the selection, which a caret would imply). However if you must do it, I believe you'll have to roll your own caret. For example, [Customizing the Caret of a WPF TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633935/Customizing-the-Caret-of-a-WPF-TextBox).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the strong internal connection in the `TextBox` between `CaretIndex` and the `Selection`.

Whenever you modify the selection with `Select()` or `SelectAll()`, the `TextBox` automatically places the `CaretIndex` at the beginning of the selection. In reverse, the `TextBox` clears the selection when you manually modify the `CaretIndex`. You can make this behavior visible, if you register for `SelectionChanged` in the `TextBox` and output the current `CaretIndex` to `Console`.

This is for a good reason, as Okuma.Scott already mentioned in his comment.

So if your desired behaviour is really required, you probably need to implement your own CustomTextBox.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
        TextBox.Text = _Text;
        System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Focus(TextBox);

        TextBox.GotFocus += (sender, e) => {
            if (_selectAll)
            {
                //I think Caret can be set here but I didn't try it
                TextBox.SelectAll();
            }
        };
```