# Selecting text and caret in a texbox on focus

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
 public class TextBoxSelectionBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public static bool GetSelectAllTextOnFocus(TextBox textBox)
    {
        return (bool)textBox.GetValue(SelectAllTextOnFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectAllTextOnFocus(TextBox textBox, bool value)
    {
        textBox.SetValue(SelectAllTextOnFocusProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectAllTextOnFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SelectAllTextOnFocus",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(TextBoxSelectionBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnSelectAllTextOnFocusChanged));

    private static void OnSelectAllTextOnFocusChanged(DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = d as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null) return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false) return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            textBox.GotFocus += SelectAll;
            textBox.PreviewMouseDown += IgnoreMouseButton;

        }
        else
        {
            textBox.GotFocus -= SelectAll;
            textBox.PreviewMouseDown -= IgnoreMouseButton;

        }
    }

    private static void SelectAll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null) return;


        textBox.SelectAll();
        textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
    }

    private static void IgnoreMouseButton(object sender, 
        System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null || textBox.IsKeyboardFocusWithin) return;
        textBox.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;

    }
```

The textbox in question is an editable cell.

Once the cell is double clicked, i want a selectall of the text as well as a caret blink at the end of the text, on getfocus.

The text is highlighted correctly.

But setting the caret at the end is deselecting the highlighted text.

i cant do both at once. how to accomplish this?

I have tried selection start,length and other approaches.nothing works.

Comment: What is the purpose of combine that two action? Maybe have other way if I can know more clearly.

Comment: If you have the `Text` selected what difference does it make where the caret is? If you start typing it will replace the existing selection so doesn't matter where the caret is. Just like @Sakura asked.

Comment: You can't do that without implementing your own textbox control. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263548/wpf-textbox-selectall-and-show-caret-at-the-same-time

Comment: @sakura my employers favor the rename file approach in windows for cell editing...thats why

Comment: @user1914725 The standar textbox doesn't blink the caret if have any text being selected!